# SAT elementary number theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $0 < pt < 1$, and $p$ is a negative integer, which of the following must be less than $–1$?

A. $2p$

B. $2t$

I think $t<0$ so both $2p$ and $2t$ must be less than $-1$. The answer is A. How am I wrong?

Comment: p is a negative INTERGER, meaning it can only be -1, -2, -3, -4, -5... etc., not a decimal, thus twice the largest case is -2, which is smaller than -1. t can be a decimal so 2t can be greater than -1, take the case t = -0.25 and p = -3

Comment: $p$ negative, $pt>0,$ means $t<0.$ But, must it be less than $-1?$

Comment: in particular $-1< t < 0$ in order for the first inequality to hold.

Comment: @DaneBouchie I think you mean $2t$ can be greater than -1...

Comment: @Thomas Andrews Yes, thanks for the correction

Answer (score 2):

Use the inequalities given to deduce that
$1/p < t < 0$.

Now what happens if, for example, we choose $p = -10$?

Comment: I don't think this is enough to answer the question.

Comment: @Théophile perhaps now it is clearer?

Comment: Yes, I think that's a helpful addition. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, we are given that $p$ is a negative *integer*. Meaning it can be something like $-1, -2, -3, -4$. When it is multiplied by $t$, it becomes a *positive* number that's less than $1$, in other words a decimal. What would $t$ be then? It would have to be two things - negative to make the product positive, and $\frac1{>p}$ to make it a decimal less than $1$ (the denominator is greater than the numerator for a decimal less than $1$).

With this information, if $C$ is some arbitrary positive integer, you can conclude that $p=-C$ and $t=-\frac1{>C}$. Which must be less than $-1$? Well, $-2C$ is less than $-1$ for all $C$, but $-\frac2{>C}$ is not always less than $-1$. In the negative "zone," a number like $-0.5$ is greater than $-1$. The answer is therefore **A**.

Also a tip for taking the SAT - When in doubt, just plug in numbers.